# How to perform DOM manipulation in Angular components?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular5

How do we get hold of DOM elements in Angular (Version 2.x and above)? The basic functions like addClass, removeClass etc are not availble in typescript so how do we do these DOM manipulations in angular components? Please suggest if any. TIA

Comment: You can use structural directives, default or custom ones. For example, to add and remove classes, you would use *ngClass https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Comment: @AlexandruPufan - thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reach your DOM elements by using ViewChild decorator in this way:

```
@Component({
    ....
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'
})

export class MyComponent{
  @ViewChild('selector') private someName;
  constructor() {
     //this is your dom
     //this.someName.nativeElement
  }

}
```

and in your template class you got to specify who is that selector

```
<div #selector> </div>
```

or you can use ElementRef class

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit,ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

export class MyComponent  implements  AfterViewInit {

  constructor(protected elementRef: ElementRef) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
       //you can reach your dom element by using
       //this.elementRef.nativeElement
   }
}
```

You are free to use 3th party libs like Jquery for addClass, removeClass within typescript.

Answer (score 7):

> The basic functions like addClass, removeClass etc are not availble in typescript

They are available. Everything that can be done in JS can be done in TypeScript. You can also use `jQuery` while it's discouraged to be used with Angular2

Some explanation how to get a reference to an element
[angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

That being said, in Angular2 you should avoid modifying the DOM imperatively but instead use binding with structural directives like `*ngFor`, `*ngIf`, ..., binding like `[class.class-name']="true"` or directives like `ngClass`.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/