# Get DOM element from service in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have root component in my hierarchy, called "root-app". Also i have router and few components, which loaded by this router. Than i have a service, which control  page navigation. I need to get one element

`<img #animationDetails src='..' alt=''>`

from each component after it is loaded, from this service. How i can get element from service after it is loaded by router.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get DOM elemnt form service. I wonder why would you even need to get the element from service. You can manipulate the DOM when services return the observables inside component callbacks. Take a look at this question on how to perform DOM manipulation from components in Angular: [How to perform DOM manipulation in Angular components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464794/how-to-perform-dom-manipulation-in-angular-components)

Comment: i want to get element (topOffset and leftOffset) to animate another img while loading new component!