# Correct way to do DOM Manipulation in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know there are some similar questions but none answer my question.

Basically what is the correct way to manipulate the DOM in angular say I have this.

**html**

```
<button id="buy-now">BUY NOW</button>
```

and when you click the button I want the button to turn purple so in pure javascript you would write something like

**javascript**

```
changeColour() {
   const b = document.getElementById('buy-now');
   b.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
}
```

now In Angular I have been doing it this way, but recently noticed people saying this is not correct??

What is the correct way to manipulate the DOM in angular, and how would I rewrite my example to reflect this corrected way??

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

To be clear, I know in Angular I can do this

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="changeColour()" id="buy-now">BUY NOW</button>
```

**TS FILE**

```
changeColour() {
   const b = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#buy-now');
   b.style.backgroundColour = 'purple'
}
```

but is this the appropriate way to manipulate the dom??

Changing the button colour was only a quick example, I mean for any type of DOM Manipulation

Thanks

Comment: Check out the docs for NgClass: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive What you sent me is for Angular 1

Comment: @Chris yes I know about NgClass this isnt just for changing a button class, Its for any and all DOM Manipulation in Angular 2+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform DOM manipulation in Angular components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464794/how-to-perform-dom-manipulation-in-angular-components)

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I guess I don't follow your question. What type of DOM manipulation are you attempting to do that wouldn't be handled by many of the suggestions listed below?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any change to a document's aesthetics like page navigation `(routing)`, item selection `(ngIf)`, loop iterations`(ngFor)` etc. is `DOM Manipulation`. It can be either `property` driven or `event` triggered or `reference` handled.

Angular offers multiple ways to handle `DOM Manipulation`.

1. **`EVENT BINDING`**:

   The flow of information from `elements` in a component to the corresponding component's `class` is event binding `(HTML Template to TS)`. Event binding works without having to define a `template reference variable.` This is the best and the easiest method to manipulate DOM elements. `()` denotes `event binding`.

   Below is the snippet for our example:

   **HTML**

   ```
   <button (click)="changeColour()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': buttonColor}">BUY NOW</button>
   ```

   **TS**

   ```
   buttonColor : string = 'grey'
   changeColour() {
       this.buttonColor = 'purple'
   }
   ```

   Angular also has a feature to allow event listener to be implemented only on a `particular event`, e.g when `enter key is pressed`, `mouse clicked` or a `combination of keys is pressed`.

   Below is the snippet for our example:

   **HTML**

   ```
   <button (keyup.control.shift.enter)="changeColour()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': buttonColor}">BUY NOW</button>
   ```

   The `colour` of the button becomes `purple` when `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` is pressed.
2. **`@HostListener and @HostBinding`**:

   This is similar to `event binding` and `property binding` in angular.

   `@HostBinding('value') val;` is  same as `[value]="val"`

   and
   `@HostListener('click') click(){ }` is same as `(click)="click()"`.

   `@HostBinding` and `@HostListener` are defined inside `directive` whereas `[]` and `()` are defined inside the `component template`.

   Below is the snippet for our example:

   **HTML**

   ```
   <button class="c_highlight">BUY NOW</button>
   ```

   **TS**
   `(host.directive.ts)`

   ```
   @Directive({
       // Notice the . in selector => this directive will work for DOM with the c_highlight class 
       selector: '.c_highlight'
    })

    export class HostDirective {

        @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') c_color = "red"; 

        @HostListener('click') c_onclick() {
            this.c_color = "purple" ;
        }
    }
   ```
3. **`Renderer2`**:

   This is basically a `wrapper` over the `browser API for DOM Manipulation`. The Renderer2 API can be run `across platforms` other than the DOM and you can provide your `own Renderer2 implementation`, unique to a platform. There are multiple DOM manipulation `methods` present for the same like `setStyle()`, `createElement()`, `createText()`, `appendChild()` etc. and we can implement our own `custom` methods too. This is similar to the `template reference variable` in your example and we are using the `reference` to the element to `modify` its `properties`.

   Below is the snippet for our example:

   **HTML**

   ```
   <button (click) = "onClick()" #abcd>BUY NOW</button>
   ```

   **TS**

   ```
   @ViewChild('abcd') 
   private abcd: ElementRef;   
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
   }
   onClick() {
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.abcd.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor','purple');
   }
   ```

   Read More - https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2
4. **`Template Reference Variable`**:

   This involves creating an `id (reference)` for the element. This is similar to the `jquery` approach wherein each element can have an `id` and events can be defined on these elements by using the `getElementById()` method. Example (as shown in your question):

   **HTML**

   ```
   <button (click)="changeColour()" id="buy-now">BUY NOW</button>
   ```

   **TS**

   ```
   changeColour() {
       const b = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#buy-now');
       b.style.backgroundColour = 'purple'
   }
   ```
5. **`fromEvent()` from `rxjs`**:
   This is similar to defining an `Event Listener` on an element. The `fromEvent` method creates an `Observable` that emits events of a specific type coming from the given element. Only the `reference` for the element has to be declared; the event is `associated` with this reference. Example:

   **HTML**

   ```
   <button #abcd>BUY NOW</button>
   ```

   **TS**

   ```
   @ViewChild('abcd') 
   private abcd: ElementRef;   
   ngOnInit(){
       fromEvent(this.abcd.nativeElement, 'click').subscribe(res => this.abcd.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'purple');
   }
   ```

   **SUMMARY**:

   The choice for the technique used for `DOM Manipulation` depends solely on the `developer`. Each of these methods have their own `benefits` and `trade-offs`; like for Event Binding, `performance` can be relatively slower when a large list is being modified as the `change detection cycle` can only run again once this function returns. Method 1 and 2 are the `best angular practices` as these `avoid creating references` for elements which can be risky and can make your application more `vulnerable` to `XSS` attacks as pointed out by @Chellapan.

Answer (score 3):

According to Angular Documentation Using Element Ref is Vulnerable

> Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more
>   vulnerable to XSS attacks. Carefully review any use of ElementRef in
>   your code. For more detail, see the Security Guide.

Use Renderer2 to manipulate the DOM.

Create a Template Ref in template and pass it to the changeColour method and Use renderer2 service which provide setStyle method to set the style of the element

**component.html**

```
<button #button (click)="changeColour(button)">BUY NOW</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

changeColour(element: HTMLElement) {
  this.renderer.setStyle(element.nativeElement, 'backgroundColour ', 'purple');
}
```

Ref:https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#security-risk

Answer (score 2):

You can access the DOM element in the template with a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-):

```
<button #btn (click)="btn.style.backgroundColor = 'purple'">BUY NOW</button>
```

Or you can pass the variable to a method:

```
<button #btn (click)="changeColor(btn)">BUY NOW</button>
```

and modify the element in code:

```
changeColour(element: HTMLElement) {
   element.style.backgroundColour = 'purple';
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dc3ypd?file=src/app/app.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: I know I could write it inline my question is, is that the correct way to manipulate the dom in Angular, I will update my question to be clearer

Comment: Does this hold true for any and all DOM Manipulation?? I'm not too concerned with changing the colour of one button, My question is more for advance DOM Manipulation, the colour changing was just an example

Comment: The template reference variable gives you access to the DOM element. You can do what you want with it in code. In some circumstances, you may need to access it with `@ViewChild("btn")` in code. It depends on the specific context and requirements.

Comment: Another way to manipulate the DOM is with `Renderer2`, as explained in [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/).

Comment: right yes this is similar to another article I was reading, and I was wondering if that was the recommended way or something else was the recommended way instead of manipulating the DOM Directly

Comment: In my opinion, the preferred way is with template reference variables, when possible. The `Renderer2` would be used in directives or for the host element.