# How do I add an eventlistener to wait for a click anywhere and close a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

How do you add an event listener to wait for a click on the page and have a div fade out?
Here's some of the code that I'm working with

HTML:

```
<div id="popup" class="intro">
        <h1 class="hello">
            <span class="introText">Hey</span><span class="introText"> There!</span><br><br>
        </h1>
</div
```

JS:

```
var popup = document.getElementById("popup")

document.onclick = funciton() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
}
```

Just started taking front-end development a little bit more seriously and I'm a little bit of a noob as far as JavaScript goes. Please let me know if you need more information on my setup!!

But if possible, I do in fact want the div to fade out once the browser detects a click and if you know how this process would work please elaborate!!

Comment: you can check this answer... :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484988/angular-12-1-add-html-element-using-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event listener

```js
var popup = document.getElementById("popup")

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('Popup will hide')
    popup.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: This runs perfectly. Thank you.